# Combine and Minification Failed

Tags: minify

We use CombineAndMinify in our production environment. However, we have our own custom JSHandler and now we are seeing a lot of exceptions in our production log

we are getting 2 kinds of exceptions and i think they may be related. It says minification failed. and directly following in IO race condition, has anyone seen this before?

```
2013-09-30 14:26:01,552 [26] ERROR     KenticoWhiteLabelCore.KenticoCore.CTV.HttpHandlers.Impl.JsHandler - Minification failed
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Probable I/O race condition detected while copying    memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.
   at System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffsetBytes, Array dst, Int32 dstOffsetBytes, Int32 byteCount)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
  at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
  at Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.CustomErrorReporter.Warning(String message, String sourceName, Int32 line, String lineSource, Int32 lineOffset)
  at Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Warn(String message, Boolean showDebugString)
   at Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.PrintSymbolTree(Int32 linebreakpos, Boolean preserveAllSemiColons)
   at Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(Boolean isObfuscateJavascript, Boolean preserveAllSemicolons, Boolean disableOptimizations, Int32 lineBreakPosition)
   at KenticoWhiteLabelCore.KenticoCore.CTV.HttpHandlers.Impl.JsHandler.Minify(String rawSource) in f:\BuildAgent2\work\5a56097309e7e8db\src\KenticoCore\CTV\HttpHandlers\Impl\JsHandler.cs:line 83
   at   KenticoWhiteLabelCore.KenticoCore.CTV.HttpHandlers.CombineAndMinifyHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in f:\BuildAgent2\work\5a56097309e7e8db\src\KenticoCore\CTV\HttpHandlers\CombineAndMinifyHandler.cs:line 216
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/vincpa/RxLoader

Comment: Hi, we can't really try another 3rd party tool ..unfortunately.